# Uncaught ReferenceError: AudioWorkletProcessor is not defined in flutter web

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, web-audio-api

I am trying to use audio worklets from web audio api to get mic input and displaying in a wave in a flutter app, I use the dart js package in order to call the javascript functions. The code works well, but I do get an error in console that says

> Uncaught ReferenceError: AudioWorkletProcessor is not defined

However after building flutter web, and unpacking as a chrome extension I get this error again, and I believe it is stopping the app from opening.

[image]

this is how I add the module

```
    await audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule('volume-processor.js');
```

and volume-processor lives in the same directory as the main thread. What am I missing?

Appreciate any tips on this.